# Why can't one compare a function pointer to a template function without explicit & on function name?

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

Consider the following code:

```
void func(int) {}
template<typename T> void templatedFunc(T) {}
int main()
{
    void (*p)(int) = func;

    bool test1 = p==func;
    //bool test2 = p==templatedFunc<int>; // compilation error
    bool test3 = p==&templatedFunc<int>; // but this works
}
```

If you uncomment the `test2` line and try to compile the code with g++, you'll get the following error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:8:21: error: assuming cast to type ‘void (*)(int)’ from overloaded function [-fpermissive]
     bool test2 = p==templatedFunc<int>; // compilation error
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I get this result on g++ 5.3.0 and 6.2.0. At the same time, compilation with clang++ 3.6.0 succeeds without warnings.

Which compiler is correct according to the Standard here — g++, which gives an error or clang++, which doesn't?

And if g++ is right, then why is there such an asymmetry with normal functions vs templated functions regarding the need of explicit address-of operator?

Comment: My common sense tells me clang is right in this situation, since a fully specialized function template (or rather an instantiation) is considered a normal function and thus should act like such.

Comment: Does it allow you to do `void (*p)(int) = templatedFunc<int>;`, or does that require the `&` as well?

Comment: BTW, the idiomatic way is to use `&`.

Comment: @TripeHound strangely, g++ doesn't complain in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a gcc bug, and you are in a corner case, in the C++ standard, *Address of overloaded function* §13.4 ([over.over]/1):

> A use of an overloaded function name without arguments is resolved in certain contexts to a function, a
>   pointer to function or a pointer to member function for a specific function from the overload set. A function
>   template name is considered to name a set of overloaded functions in such contexts. The function selected
>   is the one whose type is identical to the function type of the target type required in the context. [ Note:
>   That is, the class of which the function is a member is ignored when matching a pointer-to-member-function
>   type. — end note ] The target can be:
>
> (1.1) — an object or reference being initialized (8.5, 8.5.3, 8.5.4),
>
> (1.2) — the left side of an assignment (5.18),
>
> (1.3) — a parameter of a function (5.2.2),
>
> (1.4) — a parameter of a user-defined operator (13.5),
>
> (1.5) — the return value of a function, operator function, or conversion (6.6.3),
>
> (1.6) — an explicit type conversion (5.2.3, 5.2.9, 5.4), or
>
> (1.7) — a non-type template-parameter (14.3.2).
>
> The overloaded function name can be preceded by the & operator. An overloaded function name shall not
>   be used without arguments in contexts other than those listed. [ Note: Any redundant set of parentheses
>   surrounding the overloaded function name is ignored (5.1). — end note ]

Do you see what is lacking in the list from (1.1) to (1.7)... built-in operators!

If you declare an overload of `operator ==` both gcc will not complain with the comparison, more than that you do not have to explicitly specialize the template function:

```
void func(int) {}
template<class T>
void templatedFunc(T) {}
struct s{};
bool operator==(s, void(*)(int)){return false;}
int main()
{
   void (*p)(int) = templatedFunc;

   bool test1 = p==func;
   bool test2 = s{} == templatedFunc<int>; // no error - no overload resolution
   bool test3 = s{} == templatedFunc; // no error - overload resolution
   bool test4 = p == templatedFunc<int>; // gcc error, but not an error -
                                         // no overload resolution
 //bool test5 = p == templatedFunc; // error - overload resolution not
                                 // performed for built-int operators

}
```

`test2` and `test3` compiles with gcc. `test4` does not compile on gcc, but there are no overload resolution, you explicitly specialized the function. It really should compile. `test5` does not compile as stated in the standard. In this case gcc produces the exact same error message as for `test4`. This is surely a gcc bug.