# error assuming cast to type xxx from overloaded function on gcc

Tags: c++, c++17

i hit an error on gcc that doesn't occur on clang

```
template<typename T>
int invoke_func(T a) {
    return a;
}

bool test(int(*ptr)(int))
{
    return ptr == invoke_func<int>;
}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Tpa1gf)

error:

```
<source>: In function 'bool test(int (*)(int))':

<source>:9:19: error: assuming cast to type 'int (*)(int)' from overloaded function [-fpermissive]

     return ptr == invoke_func<int>;

                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

is gcc right to reject this code ?

after further testing replacing `invoke_func<int>` by `&invoke_func<int>` works on gcc and clang.

but why is the `&` required here when it isn't in expression like `int(*ptr)(int) = invoke_func<int>;` ?

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/B3Zt32)

Comment: It would be very useful if you also told us the error messages that GCC emits (in full and complete, of course).

Comment: to me it looks like a gcc bug. But that's just my feeling.

Comment: Not sure if it is a bug or not but every other compiler on godbolt compiles the code.  IMHO it should compile as is.

Comment: Converting the name of a function overload set into a function pointer overload resolution followed by a decay operation.  gcc is claiming that in this context that shouldn't happen automatically.  Now `int(*ptr)(int) = invoke_func<int>` is a case where it clearly happens (overload resolution through conversion to a function pointer; don't even need the `<int>` here).  I'd have to standard delve to see if `==` can also cause overload resolution.

Comment: @bolov i agree that it looks like a gcc bug but this error message looks very on purpose

Comment: @Tyker Would you like quotes from the standard backing up the answer?

Comment: @NathanOliver if possible

Answer (score 2):

There is no overload resolution involved, so message is certainly a GCC bug at the very least. There appears to be a bug report: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=81059

Edit: When searching for standard rule, I stumbled upon an existing answer to a duplicate, which explains the corner case: [Why can't one compare a function pointer to a template function without explicit & on function name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42509344/why-cant-one-compare-a-function-pointer-to-a-template-function-without-explicit)